# How can I pass value out of anonoymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to sent response from node server to client instead of greeting the return value of function Stats.calculate(), but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
router.post('/calc', (req, res) => {      
    request.get('a secret url api', (err,res,bodyJson) => {
        if(err) console.log('error');
        if(res.statusCode !== 200 ) console.log('error');
        Stats.calculate(bodyJson, req.body.firstVal, req.body.secondVal);
    });
    res.json({greeting: "ciao"});
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: does shifting `res.json({greeting: "ciao"});` inside `request.get` solves your problem?

Comment: nope :/ TypeError: res.json is not a function

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `res.json` inside the callback:

```
router.post('/calc', (req, res) => {      
    request.get('a secret url api', (err, response, bodyJson) => {
        if(err) console.log('error');
        if(response.statusCode !== 200 ) console.log('error');
        var statsResult = Stats.calculate(bodyJson, req.body.firstVal, req.body.secondVal);

        res.json({result: statsResult});
    });

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am getting error: TypeError: res.json is not a function

Comment: @xTomasM check my edited answer now. The problem was because the "res" parameter in the request.get was overriding the  "res" from router.post

Comment: I only renamed the inner one to "response"

Comment: You are my hero ;) It works!